# Django error when creating superuser django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: auth_user

Tags: python, sql, django

I am pretty new to django. All of a sudden I ran into this error when trying to create a superuser from windows command prompt using

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

When I enter it, I get this error

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: auth_user
```

I created a brand new virtual environment and project but I keep getting this issue. Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: maybe need to do migrations first? `python manage.py migrate`

Answer (score 0):

As the error shows, there is no such table `auth_user`.

`auth_user` is the table which will store the user information but that has not yet been created in the database.

To do so, run the command;

```
python manage.py migrate
```